# Mongoid infinite loop on query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, mongoid, mlab

I use mongolab and monogid on heroku instance.

I can access my models inside rails console and create them.

However - calling `Model.first` / `Model.find_or_initialize_by` causes infinite loop

```
MOPED: xx:29454 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} runtime: 7.8211ms
  MOPED: xx:29454 QUERY        database=heroku_zl6cgccm 

collection=calculations selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 1.6873ms
MOPED: xx:29454 QUERY        database=heroku_xx collection=calculations selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 5.3479ms
  MOPED: xx:29454 QUERY        database=heroku_xx collection=calculations selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 8.8738ms
```

all way down until:

```
collection=calculations selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 1544.7719ms
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bson-3.2.4/lib/bson/string.rb:79:in `to_bson_cstring'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bson-3.2.4/lib/bson/string.rb:63:in `to_bson_key'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bson-3.2.4/lib/bson/symbol.rb:58:in `to_bson_key'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bson-3.2.4/lib/bson/hash.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in to_bson'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bson-3.2.4/lib/bson/hash.rb:43:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bson-3.2.4/lib/bson/hash.rb:43:in `block in to_bson'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bson-3.2.4/lib/bson/encodable.rb:57:in `encode_with_placeholder_and_null'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bson-3.2.4/lib/bson/hash.rb:42:in `to_bson'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.7/lib/moped/protocol/message.rb:173:in `serialize_selector'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.7/lib/moped/protocol/message.rb:325:in `serialize'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.7/lib/moped/connection.rb:171:in `block in write'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.7/lib/moped/connection.rb:169:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.7/lib/moped/connection.rb:169:in `write'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.7/lib/moped/authenticatable.rb:64:in `login'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.7/lib/moped/operation/read.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.7/lib/moped/node.rb:118:in `block in connection'
... 9285 levels...
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/query_cache.rb:190:in `first_with_cache'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:199:in `block (2 levels) in first'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:545:in `with_sorting'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:198:in `block in first'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:457:in `try_cache'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:197:in `first'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:20:in `first'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/findable.rb:144:in `first'
    from (irb):10
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/bin/rails:8:in `require'
```

here is my `mongoid.yml` file:

```
production:
 sessions:
   default:
     uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>

     options:

       max_retries: 30
       retry_interval: 1
       timeout: 15

       refresh_interval: 10
```

Comment: I'm suddenly in the same situation, however mine works fine locally but not when executed on Heroku, Mongoid 4.0.2, Bson, 3.0.4

Comment: Same here - it fails on heroku, not locally

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with MongoLab, with infinite DB queries until I hit a stack level too deep. My client wanted a free DB, so I stuck with troubleshooting for a good 12 hours.

I tried everything above, as well as some other config options and then stumbled across this:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab

There is a line in there that I had overlooked: "If you’re using MongoDB version 3.0 (all MongoLab Sandboxes are version 3.0), you must use Mongoid 5.x. ". I had run a bundle update, so I didn't think much of it.

You should go in your gemfile and specify:

> gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.0'

I also had to delete my mongoid.yml and start over with

> rails g mongoid:config

mongoid.yml changes its nesting to list "clients" instead of "sessions", which really confuses Rails.

That's what fixed it for me.

Comment: I have games with dependencies locked on 3.x version, so I can't do it :/

Answer (score 2):

It looks (from your DB username) we are both using MongoHQ addon for Heroku, their lowest tier databases are sharded and I believe there's a simple config change needed to help the query route correctly once it's arrived.

> # Force a the driver cluster to behave in a certain manner instead of auto-
>           # discovering. Can be one of: :direct, :replica_set, :sharded. Set to :direct
>           # when connecting to hidden members of a replica set.
>           connect: :direct

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#anatomy-of-a-mongoid-config

I changed to Mongo Compose addon which isn't sharded and the problem disappeared immediately.

If you want to persist with MongoLab, which has the free version try tinkering with the config like:

```
options: 
  connect: :sharded
```

Further reading: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#broadcast-operations

Comment: I think you meant MongoLab instead of MongoHQ! :)

Comment: I didn't have time to test it. Just copied & pasted and got ` Optionable::Unknown (:connect is an unknown option. Valid options are: :write, :read, :database, :max_retries, :pool_size, :pool_timeout, :retry_interval, :refresh_interval, :down_interval, :ssl, :timeout, :instrumenter, :auto_discover.):`

I'll let you know in few hours

Comment: I use mongoid 4. Probably I'll have to define shard keys - http://mongoid.github.io/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html. Grep for 'Sharding' chapter (at the bottom)

Comment: Yes that looks like the ticket! Let me know if/when you get it working, I'm interested.